# How can I git clone in a composite gradle project?

Tags: git, gradle

So I tried adding this to my "composite" project

```
plugins {
    id 'com.brightsparklabs.gradle.multi-git' version '1.3.0'
}
multiGitPluginConfig {
    repositoriesDir = new File( '.' )
    repositories = [
            'a': 'git@bitbucket.org:xenworks/a.git',
            'b': 'git@bitbucket.org:xenworks/b.git',
    ]
}
```

problem is in `settings.gradle`

```
rootProject.name = 'composite'
includeBuild( 'a' )
includeBuild( 'b' )
```

if "a" or "b" are missing any of the git commands on gradle will fail to work, so I can't do `./gradlew gitClone`. This particular plugin isn't a requirement, I'm just trying to figure out how to have a "main" repo, that I can then use to clone all of it's dependencies, and yet keep those as independent libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `if` condition that checks that project is available locally.
Something like:

```
if (file("relative/dir/with/project/a").exists()) {
  includeBuild( 'a' )
}
```